# How to hide the sensitive information like email in the URL using C#

Tags: c#, .net, url, encryption, razor

Currently my URL has email displayed in it, Recommendation is to use https for communication and email needs to be displayed in the body and not in the URL.
Can some one please help me to fix this. Below is my code :

```
//URL BUILDER CODE
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Authorize(string code, string state = null)
        {
            LoginResult loginResult = this.authenticationService.LogUserInToCommonAuthentication(code);

            this.CreateSessionForUser(loginResult);

            string uri = "/";
            if (loginResult.Success)
            {
                this.Response.Cookies.Add(loginResult.AuthCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                this.logger.Warn($"Authorize -  The user {loginResult.Email} has not been authorized - ErrorCode={loginResult.Error}");
                uri += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "?User={0}&Code={1}", loginResult.Email, loginResult.Error);
                return this.Redirect(uri);
            }

            long unixUtcTimestamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
            return this.Redirect(uri + "?d=" + unixUtcTimestamp);
        }
```

Below is my index.cshtml

```
//TO DISPLAY IN THE BODY
@if (Request.QueryString["Code"] == "401" || Request.QueryString["Code"] == "500")
                    {
                    <li style="color: white; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; padding: 20px; line-height: 150%">
                        Dear User,<br>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @(Request.QueryString["User"]). This email does not seem to be authorized to use the application.
                    </li>
                  }
```

Please help me to fix this. Please comment if more information needed & Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Instead of redirect, you can return the Index view with EmailId added to ViewBag or ViewData. You can also use TempData to store data temporarily between redirections.

Comment: @Chetan : I have made use of your suggestion, pls see below code.                                                      
            ViewData["User"] = loginResult.Email;
            
                uri += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "?Code={0}", loginResult.Error);
          return this.Redirect(loginResult.Email);                                                                                   Index.cshtml :  @(ViewData["User"])        
 I have tried this way, I'm getting error saying the resource you are tryting to access has been modified. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of Session here and it worked in my case. Please find below eg:

```
// Add this in the controller
Session["Email"] = loginResult.Email;
```

And call the Session in the .html file.